# How do I access text between tags with xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I am trying to extract the text value between two tags of an XML document with `xml.etree.ElementTree`. In the following example, that would be the values `text two` and `text three`. I can extract only `text one`.
How would I find the other texts from the `<c>` tag?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(
"<foo><c>text one<sub>ttt</sub>text two<sub>uuu</sub>text three</c></foo>")

print root[0].text # text one
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext):

```
>>> z
<Element 'c' at 0x1030697d0>
>>> for i in z.itertext():
...   print(i)
...
text one
ttt
text two
uuu
text three
```