# extract text between xml tags in python

Tags: python, xml

I have xml string below and trying to print text between tags **domain, receive_time , serial and seqno** for each **entry** tag.

```
xml="""
<response status="success" code="19"><result><msg><line>query job enqueued with jobid 19032</line></msg><job>19032</job></result></response>
19032
<response status="success"><result>
  <job>
    <tenq>14:10:09</tenq>
    <tdeq>14:10:09</tdeq>
    <tlast>19:00:00</tlast>
    <status>ACT</status>
    <id>19032</id>
    <cached-logs>64</cached-logs>
  </job>
  <log>
    <logs count="20" progress="29">
      <entry logid="2473601">
        <domain>1</domain>
        <receive_time>2017/11/26 14:10:08</receive_time>
        <serial>007901004140</serial>
        <seqno>10156449120</seqno>
      </entry>
      <entry logid="2473601">
        <domain>1</domain>
        <receive_time>2017/11/26 14:10:08</receive_time>
        <serial>007901004140</serial>
        <seqno>10156449120</seqno>
      </entry>
      </logs>
  </log>
</result></response>
"""
```

using xml.etree.ElementTree. To get what's between **domain** tag I was trying *node.attrib.get('domain')* or *node.get('domain')*..please advise

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
for node in tree.iter('entry'):
        print node
```

It can be other python library too, does not have to be xml.etree. I do not want to print text between tags blindly, I need to print tag name followed by text so i.e.:

```
domain: 1
receive_time: 2017/11/26 14:10:08
serial: 007901004140
seqno: 10156449120

etc
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access text between tags with xml.etree.ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218358/how-do-i-access-text-between-tags-with-xml-etree-elementtree)

Comment: Not really..., the other one is printing text between tags blindly, I want to print tag name before text so i.e. domain: 1

Comment: `print node.find('domain').text` should do it. By the way, your xml string in the example is not parsable. Had to remove some things before making it work. You might want to look into that if you are getting a `ParseError`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You find the `domain` tag using the `find()` method first. Then, the `tag` attribute and the `text` attribute should fetch the details you are looking for -

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
for node in tree.iter('entry'):
    print('\n')
    for elem in node.iter():
        if not elem.tag==node.tag:
            print("{}: {}".format(elem.tag, elem.text))
```

Hope this helps!

Output -

```
domain: 1
receive_time: 2017/11/26 14:10:08
serial: 007901004140
seqno: 10156449120


domain: 1
receive_time: 2017/11/26 14:10:08
serial: 007901004140
seqno: 10156449120
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SAX Streams to get the inner text content of the xml element. SAX is the better way to parse xml without reading the whole XML into the memory aka DOM [Python SAX](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Sax)